# Oracle DB error Encountered the symbol "/"

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

```
create or replace procedure account_validatelogin (
p_user varchar2,
p_pw number, cur out sys_refcursor)
as
v_count number(10);
v_res number(1);
begin

Select count(*) INTO v_count from ACCOUNT a where a.USERNAME = p_user and        a.PASSWORD = p_pw;
if v_count > 0 then
v_res := 1;
else 
v_res := 0;
end if;

open cur for select v_res from dual;
end;
/
```

I do this query in Oracle db but i got error

`Error(17,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" The symbol "/" was ignored.`

Please help me to fix this, many thanks

Comment: I just ran your code in PL/SQL and it compiled without errors or warnings (after I created a dummy table `account` with columns `username` and `password` - otherwise the compiler would complain that the table doesn't exist).  Are you sure your code is EXACTLY as you posted? Line 17 is `end;` and has nothing to do with `/`, and the row with `/` has the `/` as the first character, not the third; but the error message says (17,3) which means line 17, character 3. I suspect your code is not EXACTLY what you posted.

Comment: @EJoshuaS - the / on a line by itself indicates the end of a PL/SQL program. It is needed, otherwise the compiler doesn't know the program has ended.

Comment: @mathguy - `/` is not mandatory to put, if you are compiling only 1 PLSQL block at a time. But that is not the problem. I believe what you mentioned about (17,3) is spot on. OP could not be giving us the right code/error.

Comment: @Utsav - at least in SQL\*Plus the / is required (just try it). In other front-ends perhaps you can select the block and CTRL+ENTER or whatever, but if you just type into SQL\*Plus or run from a script, you need the /. But as we both agree, that is not the problem.

Comment: Ok. I use SQL Developer so was not aware of this fact. Will keep that in mind :)

Comment: @Utsav - actually, come to think of it, / is not really a PL/SQL command; it is a SQL\*Plus command. It tells SQL\*Plus where a block ends. SQL Developer has other means to tell the compiler "this is a complete block, go ahead and compile it" (such as selecting and CTRL+ENTER or F5 or the RunScript button). Anyway, that looks like a script in the original post, and in any case even in SQL Developer if you include the `/` the code does compile without errors.